# I wanna make my discord bot ignore a user's command after they say !off

Tags: node.js, discord

im  making a bot and im new at this so i dont know how to add an command that would ignore  a user's command when they say !off its like turning the bot off for that user (like a blacklist except they can use command to add themself in it) and !on to stop ignoring the user again.

Comment: Depending on the framework you use, you can just toggle a flag, or set your own for that.

Comment: im very sorry but could you give me an example of that , im very stupid..

Comment: Show your code where you process a user input. Then try and show your attempt at recording the username and toggling a key pair value, the key being the username, and the value is a boolean whether the user is being ignored or not.

Answer (score 1):

To get this to work, you will need some kind of store.
I see that you're using node.js, you will require a key value store at the very least.

Logic wise...
You can basically add the user to the store when they hit the `!off` command.
Then each thine the user issues a command, you basically check this store if they exist.
If they do, then you ignore them. Keep in mind you need to do this for all
except the `!on` command.

For the `!on` command you simply get rid of the user from the store. If you're expecting
an extremely small group to use the bot, maybe you can use an array, however
the only downside is that it won't be persistent across server restarts.

Hope this throws some insight into how you can implement what you want to.